# Pogo silently installs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I was checking my Google Chrome extensions folder:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\
```

And I noticed an extra extension that I never installed. I took a look inside and I saw a Pogo.com icon.

Also, the strange thing is when I check **Tools > Extensions** the extension isn't listed in there.

So I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this? I've never visited that site before and looking over what it does I've never played any games that might be associated with it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this on a couple machines. What I think has been happening is that it is just a bundled link in the more recent versions. You should be able to uninstall it without any problems.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info. I find it strange though that Google would bundle this with their update.

Comment: Agreed. I think Pogo is a legitimate site though and I'm not sure why anything else would possibly want to install it, so it would have to be Google. I did see today that they have an option for Angry Birds as well, I think they are just trying to promote the Chrome Web Store.